# pluralize summaryText in clistview

Tags: php, yii

How do i pluralize the `summaryText` in Yii's `CListView`?

Here is my code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$comments,
    'itemView'=>'application.modules.comment.views.comment._view',
    'emptyText' => '<div class="alert alert-info">No comments yet.</div>',
    'summaryText' => '{count} comment(s)'
));
```

i tried putting this but failed. `{count}` is passed into my `pluralize()` function as a string. not an integer.

```
'summaryText' => '{count}'.Shared::pluralize('comment','{count}')
```

any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
'summaryText' => Yii::t('yourCategory','{n} comment|{n} comments',$comments->totalItemCount),
```

Comment: Yii::t is used for translation, and the category is used as a context of message. This means that the same message may have multiple translations depending on a context, so therefor you use category to separate them.